# Workspace switching broken after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, window-manager

After upgrade to 17.10, the WM switched to Gnome and the workspace switching is behaving strangely. I have statically created workspaces in a grid 3x3. The shortcuts for '`switch-to-workspace-X`' (with X=1..9) are all set to `['<Control>FX']` (again, with X=1..9) - set by dconf-editor in `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/`.

However, these shortcuts do something different. `<Control>F1`, `<Control>F2` and `<Control>F3` switch not to workspaces 1..3, but rather into the 1st/2nd/3rd workspace *in the current row*. For example, if I am in workspace #5, `<Control>F1` switches to workspace #4 and `<Control>F3` switches to workspace #6.

`<Control>F4` behaves even more strangely: if I am in workspace #1, #2 or #3, it switches to workspace #4. If I am in workspace #4 already, it switches to workspace #7. If I am in workspace #5..#9, it has no effect.

What can be wrong and how it can be changed into normal, Unity-like, behavior (where `<Control>FX` switches to workspace X)?

Answer (score 0):

Found what was causing the issue. I had a "Workspace Grid" extension installed, and it has a control called "Relative to current row workspace switching". Turned it off and everything's back to normal.