# Workspace layout in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, workspaces

I set up up a new laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.1 and try to customize it so that it "feels like mine". In addition to the normal system settings, gnome-tweaks already provided some more configuration options, but I miss the option to specify the layout of workspaces. Some versions of Ubuntu by default had the workspaces distributed in a row, others in a grid and in Ubuntu 18.04 they are all in one column. I really prefer the grid, but found no way to configure that. Even the keyboard shortcuts to move windows one workspace to the left/right are gone, but instead there is the option to move them one monitor to the left/right.

Any ideas about how to restore this behaviour?

Thanks,
Philipp

Comment: @karel Indeed, thanks! I found some other similar questions (https://askubuntu.com/q/973603/854337 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1033069/854337) but had some hassles to configure this "Workspace Grid" extension. Now it basically works, but seems to have some problems with relative moves left/right. I now configured only static workspace numbers.

Comment: Ok, found a way to restore the behaviour of previous versions: In the "Workspace Grid" extension, enable "Relative (to current row) workspace switching". Then use "Switch to workspace 1" and "Switch to workspace 2" keybindings for moving left and right, respectively and "Move to workspace above", "Move to workspace below" for moving up and down, respectively. Same goes for moving windows.